# How Can i Stick a Login Screen?

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter. And I'm gaining more and more knowledge in a flutter.

I make A login screen long before for my Project But Someone suggest that your login screen not be scrolled up words should stick in the same position.

Brief about my screen.--

```
       I added singleChildScrollview.I want to stop scrolling
```

below is my login screen. dart

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white12,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                        height: 200,
                        child: Image.asset(
                          "assests/man.png",
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                        )),
                    SizedBox(height: 45),
                    emailField,
                    SizedBox(height: 25),
                    passwordField,
                    SizedBox(height: 35),
                    loginButton,
                    SizedBox(height: 15),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("Don't have an account ? "),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        RegistrationScreen()));
                            // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>HomeScreen()));
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            "SignUp",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.redAccent,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              fontSize: 15,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove SingleChildScrollview

Like this

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.white12,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
     

       child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                    height: 200,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      "assests/man.png",
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    )),
                SizedBox(height: 45),
                emailField,
                SizedBox(height: 25),
                passwordField,
                SizedBox(height: 35),
                loginButton,
                SizedBox(height: 15),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text("Don't have an account ? "),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>
                                    RegistrationScreen()));
                        // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>HomeScreen()));
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "SignUp",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.redAccent,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 15,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
     
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: bottom overflow but I added a  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, Working fine as I expected but the keyboard is hiding the text fields

Answer (score 1):

Add `physics` to `SingleChildScrollView`

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
   // rest of the code here 
);
```

Though i would not recommend it as if the screen size is small and if the keyboard opens up, a render overflow will occur.

Comment: All things remained the same.Not Worked